# Fetch UIBUtton without title XCUITest swift

Tags: ios, swift, testcase, xcuitest, uitest

I have an UIButton in my view, I want to tap on it in my XCUITest case.
This button doesn't have accessibility identifier or title. There is an image in the button.

I want to know how to access an UIButton which has no title or identifier in it.

```
app.buttons["title"].tap
```

would work for button with titles.

I have tried using recorder option form Xcode, but it's providing a very long path & i am looking for any alternative solution.

```
 let element = app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 2).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 0)


XCTAssert(element.children(matching: .button).element.exists, "Button not found")
element.children(matching: .button.element.tap()
```

**NOTE:-** I am not allowed to make any changes in the application code.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I'd push back against the "I am not allowed to make any changes in the application code" requirement and give the button an accessibility identifier.

Comment: @MichaelReneer :- I have already asked the developer to add accessibility identifier & it's not feasible for them at this point of time, so i am looking for any other alternative option if available.

Comment: The other option is don't test the code until you can go back and add the accessibility identifier. You could try and use an NSPredicate and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500471-matching or you could try drilling into the hierarchy with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1501006-children, but it's going to be hard to read and end up being really fragile

Comment: @MichaelReneer Thanks for the quick response. I'll look into these alternatives.

Comment: Considering your limitations w.r.t adding the accessibility identifier .. and assuming your UI won't change quite often, you can do something like XCUIApplication().buttons.element(boundBy: ). Again, this is not an ideal solution but might work in your situation.

Comment: @EricBlair Thanks for your time. I'll try this as well